# Z3 Java API fails to detect libz3.dylib

Tags: java, z3, dylib

**TL;DR: I recently upgraded to a newer version of Z3 Java API and now I cannot load libz3java.dylib, because the libz3.dylib dependency is ignored.**

I am using [Z3 version 4.4.1](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/commit/95c9ccb2959abb46c553ec72731cd75358b80138). After compiling the project and putting the libz3java.dylib in the `java.library.path`, I get the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no libz3java in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1857)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1119)
at com.microsoft.z3.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:14)
at com.microsoft.z3.Global.ToggleWarningMessages(Global.java:86)
```

The library is in the correct path though. When reading the `Native.java` file in com.microsoft.z3.jar (autogenerated [here](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/z3-4.4.1/scripts/update_api.py#L573)), we can see that it is in fact the `System.loadLibrary("z3java");` call that fails.

So I tried loading the library manually:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.load("/tmp/z3/build/libz3java.dylib");
}
```

The result I got was:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /private/tmp/z3/build/libz3java.dylib:
  dlopen(/private/tmp/z3/build/libz3java.dylib, 1): 
    Library not loaded: libz3.dylib
Referenced from: /private/tmp/z3/build/libz3java.dylib
Reason: image not found
```

The error indicates that the libz3.dylib needs to be loaded first. So I tried loading it by hand.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.load("/tmp/z3/build/libz3.dylib");
    System.load("/tmp/z3/build/libz3java.dylib");
}
```

Unexpectedly, it yields the exact same error. **The load of libz3.dylib succeeds, but has no effect whatsoever.**

- Z3: 4.4.1
- Java version: 1.8.0_25-b17
- OS: OSX 10.11.1 (El Capitan)

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For bug reports, please use our issue tracker [here](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues). Before submitting a bug though, please make sure that your libz3.dylib and your java installation are both 64-bit, otherwise this kind of behavior happens frequently and doesn't yield any useful error messages, it would look like the load is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the issue by patching **libz3java.so** to find its dependency on the same location with:

```
patchelf --set-rpath '.:$ORIGIN' libz3java.so
```

If you are interested in the background, you can read at http://enroute.osgi.org/appnotes/native-libraries.html

And how to install patchelf is here: https://installion.co.uk/ubuntu/vivid/universe/p/patchelf/install/index.html